# Timer and TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand how to use a timer.

In my MainActivity.class, inside on create method, i have this code

```
  Timer  timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask updateM = new GestioneSlide();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateM , 1000, 5000); // i want to do a thing every second   for 5 seconds
```

then i have another class where i override the method run, and where i want to write something in a texview that is in my MainActivity.class

```
class GestioneSlide extends TimerTask {


        @Override
       public void run() {
            MainActivity.TextViewName.setText("bla  bla");
            }

    }
```

My app crash, if i delete the `MainActivity.TextViewName.setText("bla  bla");` i have no problem. Probably i can't write in that textview that way
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer does not fire its actions in GUI thread. Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to switch into it. Assuming GestioneSlide is the inner class of your Activity, write

```
   class GestioneSlide extends TimerTask {

   public void run() {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           MainActivity.TextViewName.setText("bla  bla");
        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a Handler and show msg inside handler.

```
  private class mainTask extends TimerTask
            { 
                public void run() 
                {
                    toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            } 
    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
```